# Get-Acl : Cannot find path

Tags: powershell, path, acl

I'm getting this error when I'm running my script and I don't know how to fix it.

Basically, the operation of the script is: copy a folder, user enter the name of the new folder and the permissions are cloned.

```
Get-Acl : Cannot find path '\\SERVER\Work\TEst' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\felipe\Desktop\Script\NewProjectFolder\NewProject-WP_- 
_ProductionV3.ps1:125 char:8
+ $acl = Get-Acl $NewNetworkPath
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-Acl], 
ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
GetAcl_PathNotFound_Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\felipe\Desktop\Script\NewProjectFolder\NewProject-WP_- 
_ProductionV3.ps1:128 char:1
+ $acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

The folder 'TEst' does exist (the name has been given by the user).

[Running the script & Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLKOY.png)

Comment: What does `Test-Path '\\SERVER\Work\TEst' ` return?

Comment: Does `Get-Item -LiteralPath '\\SERVER\Work\TEst' | Get-Acl` work?

Comment: Hi @LievenKeersmaekers, thanks for your reply! It returns the location of the new folder \\SERVERNAME\Drive_Name\TEst --> Name of the new folder. Almost sure the problem is happening in this part when I have to concatenate the strings. The user has to type the name of the folder and I have to concatenate with the server path.

Comment: Hi @notjustme i can't set the -LiteralPath because the user chooses the name of the new folder. In this example is TEst but it could be anything. I think it's something on the path because the script cannot find the new path because it does not exist (but it does exist).

Comment: If the problem is concatenating the user input with the server path, then you should show us how you actually do that, Are you using `Join-Path` or the .NET `[System.IO.Path]::Combine()` function? Are you taking into account that user input needs to be sanitized to avoid the path containing invalid characters?

Comment: @FelipeSá - `Test-Path` returns `true` or `false`, not the location of the folder. Can you post a screenshot of your test?

Comment: Hi guys, I have added a picture of the script & the error message. I don't know if it makes sense but I'm getting this problem on the root folder \\SERVER-NAME\DRIVE-NAME. If I create a sub-folder like 'Test-Area' the script works fine \\SERVER-NAME\DRIVE-NAME\Test-Area . Should it be a permission problem?

Comment: Well, does the user have permission to do stuff to `\\SERVER-NAME\DRIVE-NAME` or only to `\\SERVER-NAME\DRIVE-NAME\<project name>`?

Comment: @notjustme yes, to be honest, the user is me - I'm running it as administrator. The problem is happening when the script tries to set the permission on this new folder and for some reason is not working on the root folder, just inside a sub-folder.

Comment: What's your idea with line 193?

Comment: @notjustme I'm trying to concatenate the new name of the folder with the original path so if my folder has a name 'Stack' the new path should be \\SERVER\DRIVE-NAME + Stack = \\SERVER\DRIVE-NAME\Stack

Comment: But you already renamed the directory to whatever was in that variable to start with on row 186. Manipulating the string afterwards seem like a horrible order of doing things even if it wouldn't be the actual problem you're having here (I dunno).

Comment: And no - on #186 you rename the directory to whatever was in `$pjname`. So if the user input was `" Stack"` (note the leading space) you've renamed it to ``\\server\drive-name\ Stack` (space included). On #193 you then do a `$pjname.Trim()` to remove any leading or trailing spaces. So anything you test or try to do thereafter doesn't reflect what you actually named the dir to begin with in this particular scenario.

Comment: @notjustme I got you, thanks for your help! What's your suggestion to use instead of trim? Probably that's the problem I'm having to concatenate them.

Comment: Using Trim is fine but do it before you actually rename the directory.

Comment: Hi @notjustme, thank you! What's your suggestion to join two paths? One is the server directory \\SERVER\DRIVE-NAME and the second one is the name that the user chose for the folder. Something like \\SERVER\DRIVE-NAME + FOLDERNAME

Comment: The way you are doing it shouldn't really be a problem. But if you name a directory `\\server\   DIR   ` then you can't modify that string and expect to find something at the modified location (`\\server\DIR`).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the file name is too long it gives the same. You will not be able to open the file from file explorer as well. It will say that file name is too long